# Xcode 4 External Build System -> Product -> Edit Scheme... -> Run -> Executable -> a.out greyed out

Tags: xcode4

I go through a lot of sample exercises in programming books and generally use a.out as the default output. For some odd reason, it seems that literally overnight Xcode 4 has decided to "grey out" a.out from the Run -> Executable selection of the Edit Schemes window (image link below).

Now, I can get around this by just naming my output program to something other than the default a.out, but I want to understand why this problem literally happened overnight (I created an OpenGL exercise program with a.out before I went to sleep). I did not update Xcode 4 (current version 4.0.2). I looked online and read that a.out is recognized as an executable on linux but may not be recognized on mac, so I ran previous a.out binaries I created by double clicking on them and running via terminal: worked fine.

I'm going to try downloading Xcode 4.2 and see if that solves my issue but I would really like to know why this happened. Has anyone else experienced this?

[image]